# Access to all array elements from a void pointer parameter passed to a function compliant with MISRA Rule 17.4

Tags: c, embedded, void-pointers, misra

Only embedded C.

I need a function to copy unsigned data from a 4-bytes array byte per byte to an output parameter (both passed as reference). Function should be MISRA 17.4 compliant and should support different unsigned integer datatype for output parameter (considering input will always have the exact number of unsigned bytes to fill the output)

So my code is:

```
static void copy_array(const void * src, void * dest, const uint8_t lenght_bytes)
{
    uint8_t i;
    const uint8_t * src_8 = (const uint8_t*)src;
    uint8_t * dest_8 = (uint8_t*)dest;
    for (i = 0u; i < lenght_bytes; i++)
    {
        *(dest_8 + i) = *(src_8 + i);
    }
}

static void func(void)
{
    uint8_t data[] = {0xEFu, 0xCDu, 0x0u, 0x0u};
    uint16_t dest_16;
    uint32_t dest_32;

    copy_array(data, &dest_16, sizeof(dest_16));

    data[0] = 0xEFu;
    data[1] = 0xCDu;
    data[2] = 0xABu;
    data[3] = 0x89u;

    copy_array(data, &dest_32, sizeof(dest_32));
}
```

So, MISRA limits pointer arithmetic operations only to array indexing, therefore, my function is not compliant. 
Any smart way to avoid the rule or to perform same operation but MISRA compliant?

Comment: why not use `memcpy`?

Comment: dest_8[i] = src_8[i] ???

Comment: @P.W Could be a requirement that all libraries are MISRA compliant. In which case you have to roll out memcpy yourself. Quite common (and unfortunate) for strict MISRA-C implementations.

Comment: Any reason for using a homebrew function instead of the standard function `memcpy` every modern compiler knows and is able to highly optimise (and does exactly whatr you seem to intend)?

Comment: @P.W memcpy isn't compliant with MISRA 17.4 and I'm not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, this is not valid C:

```
uint8_t data[4] = {0xEFu, 0xCDu, NULL, NULL};
```

Since NULL might be a null pointer constant of the form `(void*)0`. Replace `NULL` with `0` here.

---

As for the old MISRA-C:2004 requirement about array indexing being the only allowed form, it was mostly nonsense and has been fixed in the current MISRA-C:2012. That being said, there is no need for explicit pointer arithmetic in your code, so that rule makes sense here.

Simply fix the function like this:

```
static void copy_array(const void* src, void* dest, const uint8_t lenght_bytes)
{
    uint8_t i;
    const uint8_t* src_8 = src;
    uint8_t* dest_8 = dest;

    for (i = 0u; i < lenght_bytes; i++)
    {
        dest_8[i] = src_8[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lundin. You are right, not valid initialization, it was just example but I updated to avoid confusion.
Regarding your solution, I'm afraid MISRA 17.4 does not allow use [ ] at a variable declared as a pointer, not as an array.

Comment: @GianpieroTrane Of course they do, what they don't allow is pointer arithmetic with `*(ptr + n)` instead of `ptr[n]` as the former is harder to read.

Comment: Rule 17.4 Array indexing shall be the only allowed form of pointer. Arithmetic array indexing shall only be applied to objects defined as an array type.

Comment: Rule 17.4 is simply "No pointer arithmetic other than array indexing".  That being said a google search on your phrase brings up Goanna Studio - Static Analysis check rule of "Array indexing shall only be applied to objects defined as an array type."  You should ask those Goanna folks how to pass an array into a function because their examples don't cover that.

Comment: @Lundin What about the `dest`? It is declared as `uint16_t dest_16`, but MISRA 2004 explicitely states that _Array indexing shall only be applied to objects defined as an array type_. Not helpful in cases like this, but required nonetheless.

Comment: @GianpieroTrane Yes that's what my answer says: array indexing is the only form of pointer arithmetic, which the code in the answer solves. The part about not using array indexing on other objects is related to the C standard, where pointer arithmetic on pointers not pointing at an array is undefined behavior. That's what MISRA is concerned about. C does however allow us to iterate through any object by using character pointers (`uint8_t` can be considered to be a character type).

Comment: This was discussed on the MISRA-C forums back in 2007 here: https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=641, when MISRA stubbornly refused to fix it back then, without a rationale: "MISRA appreciate that function parameters declared as an array or as a pointer are equivalent.

While there is no difference between both forms, MISRA insist on the use of the array notation if it is being used to address an array."

Comment: But this was also addressed during the review of the 2012 version of the document, after which the rules were fixed. Now we have MISRA-C:2012 chapter 8.18 which is much better written and far less dogmatic. The main concern being not doing pointer arithmetic on pointers pointing at different objects. You can use `[]` on pointers just fine, but you can't use `+ - += -=` operators on them.

Comment: @ZenJ It is fine per C17 6.3.2.3 §7, since `uint8_t` is to be regarded as a character type. So either deviate from the 2004 rule, or preferably upgrade to the more sound MISRA-C:2012.